# How do install the MySQL2 gem with Ruby v2.0?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was able to install the MySQL gem using:

```
subst X: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6" 
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib\opt 
subst X: /D
```

Now I need to install the MySQL2 gem. Can some please help me?

Comment: You should study this link if you are going to post questions here so that you understand how to format your information: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your other question about starting rails server.

My recommendation is that you train using Railstutorial.  The link is [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0).

It will walk you through the process of getting a working environment running and writing Rails code.